# How to make a component of pagination in hibernate jpa,

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**This is my Controller that fetches city table from database..is there any way to create a component of pagination to use it again and again in my other JSPs..so that i just call the component and pass parameters...**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/city")
    public ModelAndView getCityPaginatedPage(@RequestParam(value="pageNumber",required = false) Integer pageNumber,@ModelAttribute ("model") AdminCityModel CityModel, BindingResult result, ModelAndView model) {

        if(pageNumber==null){
            pageNumber=1;
        }

        Page<AdminCityModel> page = service.getCityListFrom1To10(pageNumber);
        List<AdminCityModel> CityList =page.getContent();

        int current = page.getNumber() + 1;
        int begin = Math.max(1, current - 5);
        int end = Math.min(begin + 10, page.getTotalPages());
        model.addObject("page", page);
        model.addObject("CityList", CityList);
        model.addObject("beginIndex", begin);
        model.addObject("endIndex", end);
        model.addObject("currentIndex", current);
        model.setViewName("admin/city");
        return model;
    }
```

**This is my service..**

```
public interface AdminCityService {

public Page<AdminCityModel> getCityListFrom1To10(Integer pageNumber);

}
```

**This is my Service Implementation**

```
@Transactional
public Page<AdminCityModel> getCityListFrom1To10(Integer pageNumber) {
    PageRequest request =
            new PageRequest(pageNumber - 1,Constants.PAGE_SIZE, Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
    Page<AdminCityModel> res= repository.findAll(request);
    return res;
}
```

**This is my Jsp**

```
<form id="updatecity">
                    <table id="cityTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover" style="width: 50%">
                        <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th style = "text-align: center;">Id</th>
                                <th style = "text-align: center;">City Name</th>
                                <th style = "text-align: center;">Change City</th>
                              </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach items="${CityList}" var = "ctable" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="id" style = "text-align: center;">
                                        <c:out value="${ctable.id}"></c:out>
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="city" style = "text-align: center;">
                                        <c:out value="${ctable.city}"></c:out>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style = "text-align: center;">
                                        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default editbtn">Edit</button>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
    <c:url var="firstUrl" value="/admin/city?pageNumber=1" />
                    <c:url var="lastUrl" value="/admin/city?pageNumber=${page.totalPages}" />
                    <c:url var="prevUrl" value="/admin/city?pageNumber=${currentIndex - 1}" />
                    <c:url var="nextUrl" value="/admin/city?pageNumber=${currentIndex + 1}" />

<div class="pagination" id="pagination">
                        <ul>
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${currentIndex == 1}">
                                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
                                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <li><a href="${firstUrl}">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="${prevUrl}">&lt;</a></li>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="${beginIndex}" end="${endIndex}">
                                <c:url var="pageUrl" value="/admin/city?pageNumber=${i}" />
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${i == currentIndex}">
                                        <li class="active"><a href="${pageUrl}"><c:out value="${i}" /></a></li>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <li><a href="${pageUrl}"><c:out value="${i}" /></a></li>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${currentIndex == page.totalPages}">
                                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
                                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&gt;&gt;</a></li>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <li><a href="${nextUrl}">&gt;</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="${lastUrl}">&gt;&gt;</a> </li>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crate the pagination object that will be part of each request.  Create Pagination class as

```
public class PaginationPrameters{

     private int pageIndex;
     private int rowsPerPage;
     private int startingIndex;

}
```

Request will have all three fields and you construct the object in the controller. Once you have this object calculate next request pagination boundaries and update the query with that.

Answer (score 0):

The tags on your question say you are using spring-data?

Then it's easy, spring-data has a [build-in interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) that supports pageables. Let's rewrite your AdminCityService:

```
public interface AdminCityService extends CrudRepository<AdminCityModel, Integer> {
    public Page<AdminCityModel> getCityList(Pageable page);
}
```

If you need a page size of 10 and want to retrieve the first 10 AdminCityModels, you can create a [PageRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) (it implements Pageable, page-index starts with zero) and pass it into your method:

```
PageRequest request = new PageRequest(0, 10);
Page<AdminCityModel> adminCityModels = AdminCityService.getCityList(request);
```

[Page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) provides you with some helpful getters to create a nice view in your view.